# Keystone Strategy - Unusual Spam / Jobs / 'survey'

Tags: discussion, spam

Following on from the recent featured post about spam etc, I wanted to share this one, to see if I'm just being paranoid, or $something.

The email address I have on my profile is only used here, so I know that this came from here. (I'm not complaining about receiving it, my address is there, I expect a level of junk)

this is the email I originally got (from Camille DeJarnett)

> My name is Camille and I work at Keystone Strategy. We are conducting our annual study on the evolution of the cloud computing ecosystem and would like to invite you to participate.
>
> We are offering a $150 Amazon gift card for your time and insight, and at the end of our research study, will also share an anonymized summary of the results.
>
> Participation in this study will take just over an hour of your time – approximately 30 minutes for an online survey and 45 minutes for a phone interview.
>
> If you would like to participate, please schedule an interview [here](http://meetme.so/Keystone-Strategy).
>
> Thank you for your assistance. Please feel free to reach out with any questions.

Suspecting something was amiss (and having my curiosity piqued to figure out what) I followed the link (a meetme.so (?) site) the form of which contained a question about current employer amongst other things, and I replied to the email.

After a little toing and throwing I explained that I'm a contractor and have an NDA in place currently so wouldn't be able to share the name of the company I worked for.

At which point I was told that

> . It seems like we may not be able to get into the level of detail needed for this study.

and the whole thing was terminated.

My presumption is that it was a reasonably elaborate lead generation scam, paying $150 (if that part actually existed) for a run down of a companies internal I.T. system, to then go in and do a sales pitch sounds like a reasonably good buy.

Mostly a quick heads up about this...

Comment: I got a similar email on March 14, with a follow-up on March 18. Something about wanting me to review different database software on their website, in exchange for Amazon gift cards of $10-$25 per survey. The whole thing didn't really interest me, and smelled like a scam, so I didn't reply. They had my public email from SOCareers/GitHub/personal-website, not my personal one. I would be curious to know what exactly the scam is (assuming there is one, which I usually assume), and if it's more elaborate than just not-paying.

Comment: A standard NDA doesn't limit exposure of the name of a company.  A company's name is public information, and so exposure of it wouldn't violate any NDA I've ever seen.  It's possible you have some other agreements in place if you're working for a “stealth mode” company, but I don't think any legal professional would classify those stealthy agreements as “NDA”s.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson the company I am currently doing work for does have an NDA in place, it doesn't actually stop me from revealing their name (though it would limit me discussing much depth about the project) However, 1. I didn't want to reveal the company's name to an entity that I didn't trust, and wouldn't, even without an NDA 2. The company has asked me to help them protect their privacy (by virtue of an NDA) in all circumstances I am very careful with the details of those who have entrusted me to work for them.

Comment: Saying that there is an NDA in place provides a good shortcut to preventing such firms from being able to make any other form of excuse about why I should tell them something.

Comment: @MichaelB Right; as I said before, NDAs protect against non-public information, so details of a project are certainly covered whereas your involvement with the company probably isn't and the name of the company definitely isn't.  Call it a shortcut, but it's a lie.  There's no reason you shouldn't lie to a company like Keystone Strategy, but don't expect them to buy it if it's a rather obvious lie like this.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson You're right about the company name being public record (as well as mine) the thing that the NDA would protect against is my involvement with that company. If a person has a specific skillset, and a company doesn't want it publically known that they are working in that area, it is possible, and probable that they would put a clause in the NDA to prevent that information from being disclosed. And sure it is a lie, but only because the truth is 'because I simply don't trust you' While that is often useful, a lie to companies I don't care for or have dealings with, is easier

Comment: @MichaelB I've never seen an NDA with no-revealing-association clause.  In my experience, that's put in a contractor agreement (AKA work for hire), since you're not working with them until you've working with them.   NDA is a front-door agreement; CA/WFH is a end-of-meeting-handshake agreement.  But there are always unusual agreements— one can write anything they want on a piece of paper.  Since this is about you, what's in your NDA?

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson Its in no way about me, its about a company that appears to be using an ulterior motive to obtain information about companies. Telling them about the NDA and saying I couldn't  tell them the name of the company, made them immediately end the process. Which suggested it was less about research and more about harvesting company names. Which led to the conclusion I have already stated. I'm happy to accept that that could have been because they thought I was lying about the NDA. Maybe that diminishes the warning that I wrote this about. But I am irrelevant to that.

Comment: @MichaelB Fair enough.  Going flat cold like that is always a good indicator of fishiness.

Comment: I work for a market research company. It is very common for legitimate research companies to buy names from "panel companies." These are companies that provide lists of people (+email address) that may be good candidates for a particular research project. There are better and worse panel companies out there in terms of how truly participants opted in to be panelists. My instinct reading the email is the research company may well be legit, but they made a poor choice in the panel company they are working with. I took a similar survey a while back (they found me through SO) and was paid.

Comment: If they offer you less than 30 pieces of silver for the company info I wouldn't even bother. Seriously though I would watch out with anything that has 'consulting' in the name. Usually they are vendor companies and have nothing to do with IT whatsoever (or any other business they are in), they just recruit people with an adequate profiles and sell them to their customer generating profits on your work since they usually underpay as well. Also: keep in mind that they need intel on technology that particular company uses so I think your assumptions are 100% correct.